# Laplace expansion for determinants with r

Tags: r, matrix, subset

I have a 21*21 matrix. I would like to use R in order to apply laplace extension along the first row so to display only the last  step for the calculation of the determinant (2x2 matrix). 
Unluckily, despite my best efforts, I can't figure out how this could be done.

To be clearer I provide an example with a 3x3 matrix 
e.g. r <- matrix(c(1:9),3,3)
My aim is to find an expansion along the first row, so to obtain the three cofactors. These cofactors should be visualized so to distinguish the three minor matrices, the multiplying corresponding element of the matrix, and the signs of the permutation.
TO have a visual you can take a look to the first example in (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion)

Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: Hello.  In SO you're expected to provide some code or algorithm you've tried and the desired result.  Don't expect someone to write all your code for you.

Comment: I completely agree with you but I really don't know hot to approach the problem. This is way I'm looking for some hints to start from. Is this uncorrect?

Comment: Yes, this is not a site for introductory tutorials in software programming.

Comment: Well I was only asking for clarifying references, not a tutorial or a script. I am sorry if this was not clear. I'll try somewhere else. Thank you in any case

Comment: What kind of output are you looking for? Wouldn't the last step contain on the order of `20!` 2x2 matrices? Read the wikipedia section just underneath the one you posted. Using or writing out the Laplace decomposition on a 21x21 would be ludicrous, and there are many better methods.

Comment: Dear @WillBeason,I apologize if I wasn't clear. I am looking for a script so to display the last step before writing the characteristic polynomial of the matrix, which is composed by the elements of the matrix, multiplied for the corresponding minor matrix, as in the first example of the wikipedia page I quoted. I hope now you understood.
As for your comment about my "ludicrous methods", let me say two things: 1) indeed there is a reason why I posted this question 2) I hope you will find people kinder then you when you will post a question.